# Expected value, formula explanation

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YE0P.png)

I'm confused with this formula. I can't understand how we get 4-5 line from line 3.
In this formula we getting expected value from variance in line 1 by variance's propertie. Then, in line 2-3 we did some tranformation - it's ok.
In this formula b and a - some funtions of random variable. 1/k - doesn't matter.
But line 4-5 - it's magic for me.
Main questions - how we can get line 4-5 from line 3.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: You could include the image in the question instead of providing a link.
See this question [1] for more details on how the variance of the sum of some dependent random variables can be obtained. Directly working with the formula $\text{var}(X)=\mathbb E(X^2)-\mathbb E(X)^2$ is not easy to get the main formula of the variance of the sum. [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3305898/1231520

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos ok, im getting it. It was a little bit difficult for me for first time.

Comment: @Amir Thank you! I will read your link in detail. Looks like something that will be useful at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is being used here is the equality$$a_1^{\,2}+a_2^{\,2}+\cdots+a_n^{\,2}=(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)^2-\sum_{\substack{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n\\ i\ne j}}a_ia_j,$$with $a_k=\Bbb E_X\left(b(x,X^k)-\Bbb E_Xb(x,X^k)\right)$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Unfortunately, I have not seen this equality before. I will look into this expression. Thanks again.

Comment: Please note that, if $n=2$, this is just$$a_1^{\,2}+a_2^{\,2}=(a_1+a_2)^2-a_1a_2-a_2a_1=(a_1+a_2)^2-2a_1a_2.$$

Comment: Oh. Oh. It seems very familiar)
So, I didn't know about common formula.